# relation between limit of measure and limit of function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have a maybe trivial question, but I currently trap here.
Assume now I have a function sequence $(u_n)\subseteq L^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is an open bounded regular domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that $0\leq u_n\leq1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in\Omega:u_n(x)<C\})=\mu(\Omega)$$
here $C$ is just a constant and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure, then can I directly deduce that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}u_n(x)dx\leq C\mu(\Omega)?$$
And symmetrily, if I have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in\Omega:u_n(x)>C\})=\mu(\Omega)$$
can I directly obtain that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}u_n(x)dx\geq C\mu(\Omega)?$$
If not true, under what condition can I get this?

Comment: $\lim \int u_n(x)dx$ need not exist in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}u_n(x)dx\leq C\mu(\Omega)$ in the first case and $\lim\inf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}u_n(x)dx\geq C\mu(\Omega)$ in  the second case. This is immediate since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in\Omega:u_n(x)<C\})=\mu(\Omega)$ says that $u_n \leq C$ a.e. in the first case and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{x\in\Omega:u_n(x)>C\})=\mu(\Omega)$ says that $u_n \geq C$ a.e. in the second case.

In either case, $\lim \int u_n(x)dx$ need not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! So if I can prove the existence of the limit then it should be true, right?

Comment: @Emiya Yes, you are right.